# Using generics with MikroORM custom repositories?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mikro-orm

I have a base entity that looks something like this:

```js
/* src/common/entities/base.entity.ts */

import {
  Entity,
  PrimaryKey,
  SerializedPrimaryKey,
} from '@mikro-orm/core';
import { ObjectId } from '@mikro-orm/mongodb';

@Entity({ abstract: true })
abstract class BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryKey()
  _id: ObjectId;
  
  @SerializedPrimaryKey()
  id!: string;
}

export default BaseEntity;
```

...and I'm trying to create a generic custom entity repository like so:

```js
/* src/models/model.repository.ts */

import { EntityRepository } from '@mikro-orm/mongodb';
import BaseEntity from 'src/common/entities/base.entity';

class ModelRepository<T extends BaseEntity> extends EntityRepository<T> {
  async get(id: string): T | undefined {
    const entity = await this.findOne({ id });

    return entity;
  }
}
```

...however, I'm getting the following TS error:

```
Argument of type '{ id: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FilterQuery<T>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'id' does not exist in type 'FilterQuery<T>[]'
```

Any reason why this doesn't work? It seems like it should...

Comment: AFAIK this is a TS limitation of mapped types, you need casting here.

Comment: [Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QKLmGAT2QG8AoZC5YAEwC5kMwpQBzAblIF9TTCAHFADFgAG0hQAigFdoBADwAVAHzIAvCWQBtANJUQyANYQCAexjIFAXXoKdl5Jw6lqEBCLhQUbzBmS4w+AQAShB8Jhj4JlDyyiTklDCg1ADyIBAAFADuABbQEPTCYtDSsopKAJT0AApQJgC2wFiKyAA+yCBSIiJKHNyk3hi+ALImLiIhYRFgUTHIEAAekCDUvuhY-oEqC0srfniEE+GR0WVxFJgEIAjILBBg6TT0jMwgLJXINfWNEM1tHV0qMiUZAIEwgRhzfZEdRwTJwfDIMDZRoAOkSy1SGWIVGoDnKTmBnjAUig+ggUI4FG4nCAA) you can see the very same problem with a dummy mapped type.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following, how I achieved this

```
export class CachingRepository<T> extends EntityRepository<T> {
    protected _em: SqlEntityManager;
    protected entityName: EntityName<T>;

    constructor(_em: SqlEntityManager, entityName: EntityName<T>, private cacheManager: CacheManager<T>){
        super(_em, entityName);
    }

    async getAll(whereClause: any, options: any, useCache: boolean = false): Promise<T[]>  {
        let result: T[] = await this.cacheManager.get(this.entityName.toString());
        const entityName = this.entityName.toString();

        if (result && useCache) {
            return result;
        }
        else if (!result || (result && !useCache)) {
            result = await this._em.find(this.entityName, whereClause, options);
            this.cacheManager.set(this.entityName.toString(), result);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

T is the entity.